# How to add separate line to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have several group in a collectionView ,I want to add a separate line in each group.Is there good way to add?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the line you've indicated? Like between sections?

Comment: Yes the line I indicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well In my opinion, you can add a header view in each section. In header view, add a UIImageView with 1px height. then set a gray 1px height line image to this ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIview with 1px height  at the bottom of  custom collection view cell and change the color of UIview to black color.